# Finding all unique substitution combinations in Python

Tags: python, combinatorics

Given two lists of unique labels like:

```
a = ['Joe', 'Mary', 'Sue']
b = ['S0', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5']
```

How would I efficiently find all possible combinations where the elements from list `a` are substituted or mapped into list `b`? e.g. If S0 = S1 = Joe, S2 = Mary, S3 = S4 = S5 = Sue then I would have:

```
{'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Mary', 'S3': 'Sue', 'S4': 'Sue', 'S5': 'Sue'}
```

I started with this simple nested for-loop approach:

```
def iter_mapping_combos(names1, names2):
    q = [(names2, {})]
    priors = set()
    while q:
        _names2, _mapping = q.pop(0)
        key = (frozenset(_names2), frozenset(_mapping.items()))
        if key in priors:
            continue
        priors.add(key)
        for n1 in names1:
            for n2 in _names2:
                if n2 in _mapping:
                    continue
                _mapping_next = dict(_mapping)
                _mapping_next[n2] = n1
                _names2_next = set(_names2)
                _names2_next.remove(n2)
                if _names2_next:
                    q.append((_names2_next, _mapping_next))
                else:
                    yield _mapping_next

for mapping in iter_mapping_combos(['Joe', 'Mary', 'Sue'], ['S0', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5']):
    print(mapping)
```

It works, but as you can imagine, it's not that efficient and it doesn't scale well as the lengths of the lists increase. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.product` to generate the desired cartesian product:

```
from itertools import product

def iter_mapping_combos(names1, names2):
    yield from (dict(zip(names2, p)) for p in product(names1, repeat=len(names2)))
```

so that:

```
for mapping in iter_mapping_combos(['Joe', 'Mary'], ['S0', 'S1', 'S2']):
    print(mapping)
```

outputs:

```
{'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Joe'}
{'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Mary'}
{'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Mary', 'S2': 'Joe'}
{'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Mary', 'S2': 'Mary'}
{'S0': 'Mary', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Joe'}
{'S0': 'Mary', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Mary'}
{'S0': 'Mary', 'S1': 'Mary', 'S2': 'Joe'}
{'S0': 'Mary', 'S1': 'Mary', 'S2': 'Mary'}
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/BlondStalePostscript

Comment: After revisiting this question, I believe this is the most efficient method to create the desired combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Although you didn't specify your problem requirements, from the single example I gather that you need to map each element of `b` to exactly *one* element of `a` (although a given `a` element may have more than one `b` element mapped to it).  That has an exponential explosion, a total of `len(b) ** len(a)` distinct mappings.

You can shorten your code quite a bit: learn to use the `itertools` module; this is effectively an application of the `product` method, crossing six copies of `a`.  In simple terms:

```
product(*[a]*len(b))
```

Does that get you going?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the desired combinations and then use `zip`:

```
a = ['Joe', 'Mary', 'Sue']
b = ['S0', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5']
def combos(d, c = []):
  if len(b) == sum(map(len, c)):
     yield c
  for i in range(1, len(d)+1):
     yield from combos(d[i:], c+[d[:i]])

r = [[[j for _ in k] for j, k in zip(a, i)] for i in combos(b) if len(i) == 3]
result = [dict(zip(b, [i for k in j for i in k])) for j in r]
```

Output:

```
[{'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Mary', 'S2': 'Sue', 'S3': 'Sue', 'S4': 'Sue', 'S5': 'Sue'}, {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Mary', 'S2': 'Mary', 'S3': 'Sue', 'S4': 'Sue', 'S5': 'Sue'}, {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Mary', 'S2': 'Mary', 'S3': 'Mary', 'S4': 'Sue', 'S5': 'Sue'}, {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Mary', 'S2': 'Mary', 'S3': 'Mary', 'S4': 'Mary', 'S5': 'Sue'}, {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Mary', 'S3': 'Sue', 'S4': 'Sue', 'S5': 'Sue'}, {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Mary', 'S3': 'Mary', 'S4': 'Sue', 'S5': 'Sue'}, {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Mary', 'S3': 'Mary', 'S4': 'Mary', 'S5': 'Sue'}, {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Joe', 'S3': 'Mary', 'S4': 'Sue', 'S5': 'Sue'}, {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Joe', 'S3': 'Mary', 'S4': 'Mary', 'S5': 'Sue'}, {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Joe', 'S3': 'Joe', 'S4': 'Mary', 'S5': 'Sue'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that your method is over-counting by 6x (i.e. the number of items in `b`).  On my smaller sample, for example, your code produces the following which are just rearrangements of the same items:

```
[{'S0': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe'},
 {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Joe'},
 {'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Joe', 'S0': 'Joe'},
 ...]
```

Using a smaller example to demonstrate my implementation:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, permutations

a = ['Joe', 'Mary'] 
b = ['S0', 'S1', 'S2'] 

result = []
combos = combinations_with_replacement(a, len(b))
for combo in combos:
    seen = set()
    for p in permutations(range(len(b)), len(b)):
        order = tuple(combo[idx] for idx in p)
        if order not in seen:
            seen.add(order)
            result.append(order)

>>> result
[('Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe'),
 ('Joe', 'Joe', 'Mary'),
 ('Joe', 'Mary', 'Joe'),
 ('Mary', 'Joe', 'Joe'),
 ('Joe', 'Mary', 'Mary'),
 ('Mary', 'Joe', 'Mary'),
 ('Mary', 'Mary', 'Joe'),
 ('Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary')]
```

The result then needs to be encoded to the keys in `b`:

```
final_result = [{b[n]: val for n, val in enumerate(row)} 
                for row in result]
>>> final_result
[{'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Joe'},
 {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Mary'},
 {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Mary', 'S2': 'Joe'},
 {'S0': 'Mary', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Joe'},
 {'S0': 'Joe', 'S1': 'Mary', 'S2': 'Mary'},
 {'S0': 'Mary', 'S1': 'Joe', 'S2': 'Mary'},
 {'S0': 'Mary', 'S1': 'Mary', 'S2': 'Joe'},
 {'S0': 'Mary', 'S1': 'Mary', 'S2': 'Mary'}]
```